# Require password for each application to install

Tags: google-play-store, password, authentication

Since I will be lending my phone to someone else, I want my phone to ask my Google account password (or alternative authentication) each time an app is installed.

If I go to *Google Play* -> *Three bars menu* -> *Settings* -> *Require authentication for purchases*, the options are:

1. For all purchases through Google Play on this device.
2. Every 30 minutes.
3. Never.

The first option seems to be what I am looking for.
Nevertheless, I am not asked for any authentication for installing apps.

**Can this be done? How?**

Using a Samsung Galaxy J7, with Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Apps that are free don't have to be purchased -> no purchase means no password prompt.

I see two possibilities for you:

1. Delete your Google account from the device. Google apps usually sync everything to the cloud, therefore by re-adding the account everything will be restored.
2. If the device has the possibility to create a guest user account set a difficult password on your primary account and create a guest user. Guest users aren't allowed to install new apps, however they can use every app that is already installed and the app data is stored in a separate directory therefore the guest can use the apps but don't access your app data.

Comment: I understood that "purchase" included apps, regarded as being of zero cost.
I never tried purchasing a non-free app, so I cannot confirm I am seeing the expected behavior in that case.

Comment: No, have a similar problem, my 5 yr old son grubs it when i turn around and by the time its locked 10-20 "free" apps have been installed...

Answer (score 1):

A bit extreme, but consider that Google will not allow you control over installations...

Disable google play.... It wont be uninstalled, and can be re-enabled from settings, but its one more extra step at least...

Comment: When the Google Play app is disabled, then you won't get update notifications, see https://gadgetroyale.com/disable-google-play-store/  So when you disable this app, you might miss a security update for one of your apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for that! Applock will give you that functionality. To require passwords for select apps, thus allowing you to share yet protect sensitive data, or in my case, finance or $ portfolios. On Android anyhow it's called Applock.

> - AppLock can lock Facebook, WhatsApp, Gallery, Messenger, Snapchat, Instagram, SMS, Contacts, Gmail, Settings, incoming calls and any app you choose. Prevent unauthorized access and guard privacy. Ensure security.
> - AppLock can hide pictures and videos. Hidden pictures and videos are vanished from Gallery and only visible in the photo and video vault. Protect private memories easily. No pin, no way.
> - AppLock has random keyboard and invisible pattern lock. No more worry people may peep the pin or pattern. More safe!"

Hope that helps you! This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Guest account is the best method.

If your phone does not support guest user account feature:

Then probably check XDA developers - find model number of your phone-root it-
Install the stock Android - then you should get a lot of options that are better than factory installed ROM.